# Liquibase - validation failed checksum changed

Tags: liquibase, checksum, liquibase-sql

This is the first version of my changelog.sql:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset kh:1
CREATE TABLE test_table (test_id INT, test_column VARCHAR(256), PRIMARY KEY (test_id))

--changeset kh:2
INSERT INTO test_table (test_id, test_column) VALUES(3,'saket');
```

This is an update of my changelog.sql (Added a column in the first changeset):

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset kh:1
CREATE TABLE test_table (test_id INT, test_column VARCHAR(256), test_column2 VARCHAR(256), PRIMARY KEY (test_id))

--changeset kh:2
INSERT INTO test_table (test_id, test_column) VALUES(3,'saket');
```

I execute a liquibase update with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -v /changelog:/liquibase/changelog liquibase/liquibase \
--url=jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxxxxx:5432/postgres \
--changelog-file=changelog.sql --username=xxxx \
--password=xxxx update
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 changesets check sum
          changelog.sql::1::kh was: 8:46ea95d67274343c559a1c5ddc8ee33 but is now: 8:ab7361c532323a6a32bc79d230a46574
```

I understand that when running it in a productive environment, it should fail in order not to launch scripts again by mistake, but, **in a non-productive environment, how should it work?**

I imagine three solutions in a DevOps (NonProd) scenario:

1. Restore database as the first step and execute changelog for specific version.
2. For nonprod, ignore the checksum validation
3. Modify the changelog and add a new changeset with the change.- For my taste, this is the least correct

In a non-production environment, it may be necessary to make changes to SQL until the new functionality is validated. What is the best practice, and is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checksum error indicates that you are modifying a changeset that has already been executed in the particular database target.  Therefore, Liquibase does not understand why you are doing this modification.

The sql statement "CREATE TABLE test_table" cannot be executed again, so adding the additional column does not make sense.

If you want to add a column to a table that has already been created, you really only have 2 options:

1. Drop and recreate the table to include the new column
2. Alter the table to add the new column

Option 1 can be acomplished by using Liquibase rollback, followed by modifying the changeset, and then Liquibase update.
Option 2 can be accomplished by adding a new changeset.

Both are 100% valid options.